# Formatting merge messages with tsvn:* properties in tortoisesvn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I use tortoisesvn 1.7.10 Build 23359 - 64 Bit.
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html
This manual says, that tortoisesvn has it's own project properties, starting with tsvn:.
Some of them are "tsvn:mergelogtemplatetitle" and "tsvn:mergelogtemplatemsg"

But I can't see them in property editor of svn directory.
I use context menu of root directory that was checkouted from svn. Press "Properties". Then "New" - "Advanced" and I see [image: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/images/PropertyAdd.png]
https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/images/PropertyAdd.png

And there's no such tsvn properties.

These links says that this ability was added in May, 2012:
[one](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/detail?r=22915),
[two](https://web.archive.org/web/20130122123818/http://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/latest/changelog.html).
May be, it was added to 32-bit version only?

How to find them?

Comment: just type the property name in the box, even if the property isn't shown in the dropdown.

Comment: oh, thank's! I'll do this.

Comment: @Stefan, but I still can't see window like this [link](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_ru/images/mergelogmsgtemplate.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stefan has said in comments above, I need just to type the property name in the box, even if it isn't shown in the dropdown.