# Auto Formatting merge message in TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I try to configure svn properties of my project to make TortoiseSVN generate merge message logs automatically.
There's a [manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html) on TSVN site and a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877521/formatting-merge-messages-with-tsvn-properties-in-tortoisesvn) at stackoverflow.

So I edited properties of /trunk folder and set my custom **tsvn:mergelogtemplatetitle** and **tsvn:mergelogtemplatereversetitle** properties there.

But after that nothing changed. I tried to merge some commits from /branches/mybranch to /trunk. But after merging in commit window I pressed "Recent Messages" button and there're auto-generated commit messages in default format. Not in my.

What do I do wrong?

And some more questions.

1. How to open a window like in Figure 4.48 at [TSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html)?
2. Can I change format of log message in form with selecting revisions to merge?

Comment: For your first question, you are looking at the documentation for the pre-release builds of TortoiseSVN. IOW, you're reading about a feature which doesn't exist in the version you're running (unless you're running a nightly).

Comment: oh, thanks, @alroc. It's just what I needed to know.